# DNS: Record not found / rcode SERVFAIL troubleshooting

Tags: domain-name-system

I have made some DNS changes and now find my self in a situation where some DNS servers are responding "record not found" with "rcode SERVFAIL" when I lookup my domain name.

The domain name is:

getthedata.com

For example, Google's online [DIG](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/) tool currently returns the below for an "A" record query:

```
id 6721
opcode QUERY
rcode SERVFAIL
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
getthedata.com. IN A
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
```

The [whatsmydns.net DNS Propagation Checker](https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/getthedata.com) reports similar results from most of the nameservers it checks.

### History

The name is hosted with GoDaddy.

The DNS was originally with Cloudflare.

On Tuesday 19th December 2023 I shifted the domain name to a new Cloudflare account, which involved changing the authoritative nameservers at GoDaddy. I am not aware of any issues prior to this date, so I am assuming that it was this change which triggered the issue.

When I made the change, I copied over the raw zonefile from the old Cloudflare account to the new Cloudflare account.

**But I included the NS records from the old account in the zone file imported into the new account, which were the old authoritative nameservers.**

I wonder if this is the cause of my issue.

It also looks like DNSSEC may have been partially activated on the old Cloudflare account, but not at GoDaddy, and nothing in the zonefile.

On Wednesday 20th I then changed the DNS to Google Cloud, which is what it is now. I did this to reduce the complexity caused by the Cloudflare stack and aid with troubleshooting.

I am seeing traffic coming into the site, so clearly everything is working fine for some people.

My question is: How best to troubleshoot a "Record not found" / "rcode SERVFAIL" issue under these circumstances, with the objective of identifying and resolving the issue?

Comment: This is looking like a DNSSEC issue, I will post an update once this is confirmed.

Comment: DNSSEC looks healthy according to  https://dnsviz.net/d/getthedata.com/dnssec/ but incorrect name servers are a likely cause of error that persists until cached incorrect records expire.

Comment: [Whois information](https://www.godaddy.com/whois/results.aspx?domain=getthedata.com) still shows `Name Server:` GRACE.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM
and MARIO.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM - which seems quite different from what you describe it should be ...

Comment: @HBruijn on advice I tried reverting back to the original Cloudflare account and associated DNS (mario and grace) and this seems to have at least partly resolved the issue. Some CNAME records are still not working however. I think the issue is that I was not aware that DNSSEC was enabled on the domain before I attempted the transfer.